# Get list of friends' names and IDs fast

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

In my app, I get the user's friends with the following:

https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name&access_token=xxxx

The above is actually done by the Facebook Android SDK, so I'm actually creating the request like this:

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("fields", "name,id");
    asyncFacebookRunner.request("me/friends", params, "GET", listener, null);
```

I parse the JSON response like this:

```
            JSONObject data = Util.parseJson(response);
            JSONArray friendsData = data.getJSONArray("data");
            mDbAdapter.deleteAllFriends();

            for (int i = 0; i < friendsData.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject friend = friendsData.getJSONObject(i);
                mDbAdapter.addFriend(friend.getString("name"),
                        friend.getString("id"));
            }
```

The Util class is part of the Facebook Android SDK.

On my Android phone with wifi on, this takes about 15-20 seconds to send, retrieve, and parse the response (my account has about 370 friends). I've seen a few other apps that do it in about 2 seconds.  What's slowing me down here?

Comment: Maybe its due connection speed. You can speed it up a bit more using threading, depending where threading is possible. Or optimize the implementation.

Comment: It's about 10 to 15 times slower than other apps, using the same phone on the same wifi network.

Comment: Then optimization of the approach. Are you sure you are doing the same operation they do? Try threading the processing that does not require updating on the ui, or use the threading where is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only little reason for a delay I think is you database adapter, i.e. adding items while parsing through the result.

To optimize a bit, you could remove some of the assignments in your loop and add the data to the database through a single request:

```
JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
JSONArray friendsData = json.getJSONArray("data");
String ids[] , names[] = new String[friendsData.length()];
for(int i = 0; i < friendsData .length(); i++){ 
        ids[i] = friendsData .getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
        names[i] = friendsData .getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
        }

//TODO Add data to your database
```

Comment: This one was an oldie. I fixed it using exactly the solution you posted. With a list of about 400 friends, the time went from about 15 seconds to three seconds. Forgot to come back and answer it myself, thanks!